# What is the best format to deliever an illustrator logo design to a client?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, logo, cs6

Which file format is best to export from illustrator for prints & enlargements and web?

Comment: The best would probably be AI as others have explained here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: two outlined PDF. One in CMYK and one in RGB.

This enables the receiver to open and edit the CMYK file in Illustrator or any other vector program (for print). The RGB PDF can also be opened by photo editors on any resolution, for usage in social media profiles, etc. Finally, an RGB PDF can be easily converted to an SVG (by Illustrator), for usage on a website.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Go [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). Industry standard [.eps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) or [.ai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator) should work (I prefer the latter). For web usage, you could include a transparent background [png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) at a high resolution (2000px width +) and/or [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

I would also suggest you include both RGB and CMYK versions of the logo for use in web and print contexts.

**Long answer:**

When I package a logo for a client, I send them a zip, with a folder structure that ussually looks like this:

- cmyk/
- rgb/
- fonts/
- README.txt

For files, I create both rgb and cmyk versions of each of the logo variations (typically horizontal and vertical designs).

I also create color variations for each format (e.g., brand colors, possibly versions for dark and light backgrounds, etc.)

Depending on project, I will also create a “bug” that can be used for social media and/or avatars.

For just the rgb logo, I include a `2000px` wide png of each file; this is for clients that just need quick access but don't want to open, or have access to, an app like Adobe Illustrator.

I always remember to include the fonts I used when creating the logo, and/or any supporting fonts (e.g., taglines, subheads, etc.) (***Note:** While the font I use for a logo may get manipulated, there are times when having the original font is useful for scenarios where you can't include graphics and have to recreate a font-only version of the same logo.*)

For naming conventions of logo files, I generally like to do this:

> brand-name-[logo/bug/other]-[logo-variation-version-number-zero-padded].[color].[color-model].[extension]

The contents of `README.txt` may vary, but as a baseline I put:

> Use logos found in “cmyk” for print materials only.
>
> For all other purposes, use logos found in “rgb”.
>
> Company Name or Designer Name
> 555 Fake Street
> Town, ST 55555
> http://company-or-designer-domain.com

Here is an example screen shot:

[image]

Shown in screen shot above, I have a `dev/` folder that contains all of the original working files that I created during development of the logo.

I hand off the logo package as a zip file (`brand-name-logo.072016.zip`), and it contains all files mentioned above with the exception of the `dev/` folder.

Not shown in screen shot would be color swatches; I don't typically include this in the “logo zip”, but giving your client their brand colors as RGB and CMYK (and Pantone) is always a nice touch.

**YMMV.**